# How to get the result of the function Discord.PY?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have my bot, and in my help command, I wanna say what the server's prefix is. I'm using a function to do so, because I'm using custom server prefixes. The message that gets sent, isn't the result of the function, it just gives the name. Here's the help command:

```py
@commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
    async def help(self, ctx):

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Help",
        description=f"The prefix for this bot is `{get_prefix}` .\n"
                                          f"Use `{get_prefix}help <command>` for information about "
                                          f"that command. Use `{get_prefix}help <category>` for all "
                                          f"commands on that category.",
        olor=0x505050)

        embed.add_field(name="Moderation", 
        value="All moderation commands, such as kick or ban.",
        inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Fun",
        value="Fun commands to play around with, such as 8ball.",
        inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Miscellaneous",
        value="Miscellaneous commands such as bot information.",
        inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

And this is what it sends:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMsoI.png

Here's my get_prefix function if needed:

```py
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
```

Is there any way to fix this, except modifying the default help command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually call the function and pass the necessary parameters

```py
prefix = get_prefix(self.client, ctx.message)  # or `self.bot`, however you named it

embed = discord.Embed(title="Help",
    description=f"The prefix for this bot is `{prefix}` .\n"
                f"Use `{prefix}help <command>` for information about "
                f"that command. Use `{prefix}help <category>` for all "
                f"commands on that category.",
    color=0x505050
)
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! I'll accept the answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Great! Happy to help:)

Comment: PS: There's a really good guide (https://gist.github.com/InterStella0/b78488fb28cadf279dfd3164b9f0cf96) that shows how to make a "procedural" help command